# Is this set dense in some open set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (with at least two elements)  which satisfies the following property: 
$$\mbox{if $a,b \in S$ with $a<b$ then $(a,b)\cap S\not=\emptyset$}.$$

Is it true that there exists a non-empty open set $U$ such that $S\cap U$ is dense in $U$?

Any reference in the literature to this kind of sets is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $C$ be the [middle-thirds Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), and let $E$ be the set of endpoints of the open intervals that were removed in the construction of $C$. Let $S=C\setminus E$; then $\operatorname{cl}S=C$, which is nowhere dense, and $S$ is densely ordered (i.e., satisfies your requirement).

Comment: So $S$ is the set of numbers between 0 and 1 whose base 3 expansion consists of 0s and 2s and it is non-terminating. Am I right?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, that’s exactly right. (And one really need only delete *one* of the endpoints of each interval to make $S$ densely ordered.)